# Python Pandas DataFrame str contains merge if

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge the rows of the two dataframes hereunder, when *the strings* in Test1 column of **DF2** contain *a substring* of Test1 column of **DF1**.

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Test1':list('ABC'),
                   'Test2':[1,2,3]})

print (DF1)
  Test1  Test2
0     A      1
1     B      2
2     C      3

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test1':['ee','bA','cCc','D'],
                   'Test2':[1,2,3,4]})

print (DF2)
  Test1  Test2
0    ee      1
1    bA      2
2   cCc      3
3     D      4
```

For that, I am able with "str contains" to identify the substring of DF1.Test1 available in the strings of DF2.Test1

INPUT:

```
for i in DF1.Test1:

ok = DF2[Df2.Test1.str.contains(i)]

print(ok)
```

OUPUT:

[image]

Now, I would like to add in the output, the merge of the substrings of Test1 which match with the strings of Test2

OUPUT:

[image]

For that, I tried with "pd.merge" and "if" but i am not able to find the right code yet..
Do you have suggestions please?

```
for i in DF1.Test1:

if DF2.Test1.str.contains(i) == 'True':

    ok = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on= ['Test1'[i]], how='outer') 

    print(ok)
```

Thank you for your ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) values to new column and then `merge`, last remove helper column `Test3`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in DF1.Test1)
DF2['Test3'] = DF2.Test1.str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
DF = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, left_on= 'Test1', right_on='Test3').drop('Test3', axis=1)
print (DF)
  Test1_x  Test2_x Test1_y  Test2_y
0       A        1      bA        2
1       C        3     cCc        3
```

**Detail**:

```
print (DF2)
  Test1  Test2 Test3
0    ee      1   NaN
1    bA      2     A
2   cCc      3     C
3     D      4   NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

I could not respnd to jezrael's comment because of my reputation. But I changed his answer to a function to merge on non-capitalized text.

```
def str_merge(part_string_df,full_string_df, merge_column):
    merge_column_lower = 'merge_column_lower'
    part_string_df[merge_column_lower] = part_string_df[merge_column].str.lower()
    full_string_df[merge_column_lower] = full_string_df[merge_column].str.lower()   
    pat = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in part_string_df[merge_column_lower])
    full_string_df['Test3'] = full_string_df[merge_column_lower].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=True)
    DF = pd.merge(part_string_df, full_string_df, left_on= merge_column_lower, right_on='Test3').drop([merge_column_lower + '_x',merge_column_lower + '_y','Test3'],axis=1)
    return DF
```

Used with example:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Test1':list('ABC'),
                   'Test2':[1,2,3]})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test1':['ee','bA','cCc','D'],
                   'Test2':[1,2,3,4]})

print(str_merge(DF1,DF2, 'Test1'))
  Test1_x  Test2_x Test1_y  Test2_y
0       B        2      bA        2
1       C        3     cCc        3
```

Comment: what does the line `pat = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in part_string_df[merge_column_lower])` do ?